# Discover linux kernel boot options

Tags: linux, boot, kernel

Is there a cross-distribution way to know the boot parameters supplied to the kernel?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Assuming you're asking about the options passed to the current-running kernel?

1. If the /proc filesystem is in use, /proc/cmdline tells you exactly what options were passed to the kernel.

   ```
   $ cat /proc/cmdline  
   root=UUID=3630dd43-f9f9-40b1-8a5f-72c13f2b309c ro quiet splash
   ```
2. If there's no /proc filesystem, you can get an idea by finding the current kernel's entry in grub.conf or other bootloader configuration.  (Use "uname -r" to see what kernel is currently running.) This won't tell you what WAS used to boot the current kernel, just what is NORMALLY used.

Comment: Note for option 2: grub on Ubuntu uses /boot/grub/menu.lst for its configuration.  I think other systems may use /etc/grub.conf.

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing you're talking about the Linux Kernel, so there is a [set of standard parameters](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/bootparam.7.html) which it accepts.